# Optimizing async multi-request operations calling the same service

Tags: java, ajax, websocket

We are developing a document management web application and right now we are thinking about how to tackle actions on multiple documents. For example lets say a user multi selects 100 documents and wants to delete all of them. Until now (where we did not support multiple selection) the `deleteDoc` action does an `ajax` request to a `deleteDocument` service according to `docId`. The service in turn calls the corresponding utility function which does the required permission checking and proceeds to delete the document from the database. When it comes to multiple-deletion we are not sure what is the best way to proceed. We have come to many solutions but do not know which one is the best(-practice) and I'm looking for advice. Mind you, we are keen on keeping the back end code as intact as possible:

1. Creating a new `multipleDeleteDocument` service which calls the single doc delete utility function a number of times according to the amount of documents we want to delete (ugly in my opinion and counter-intuitive with modern practices).
2. Keep the back end code as is and instead, for every document, make an `ajax` request on the service.
3. Somehow (I have no idea if this is even possible) batch the requests into one but still have the server execute the `deleteDocument` service X amount of times.
4. Use `WebSockets` for the multi-delete action essentially cutting down on the communication overhead and time. Our application generally runs over `lan` networks with low latency which is optimal for websockets (when latency is introduced web sockets tend to match http request speeds).
5. Something we haven't thought of?

Comment: What kind of feedback do you want to provide to the user while deletion is in progress? I think you should take this in account while finding the best solution. If it is something like `deleting document 1 of n - xyz.doc`  then option `2` should be fine. I would even go and refactor the front end deletion request code to use the multi delete even for one single document, this way you will have one front end code that handles it all and the backend code remains untouched.

Comment: That is a good idea on how to keep the end user occupied while making multiple requests... However I'm still looking for optimal performance here regardless of user experience (it is cool to see a progress bar for each action but if it needs 1 second for each request it becomes too much).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending N Ajax calls or N webSocket messages when all the data could be combined into a single call or message is never the most optimal solution so options 2 and 4 are certainly not ideal.  I see no particular reason to use a webSocket over an Ajax call.  If you already have a webSocket connection, then you can certainly just send a single delete message with a list of document IDs over the webSocket, but if an Ajax call could work just as well so I wouldn't create a webSocket connection just for this purpose.

Options 1 and 3 both require a new service endpoint that lets you make a single call to delete multiple documents.  This would be recommended.

---

If I were designing an API like this, I'd design a single delete endpoint that takes one or more document IDs.  That way the same API call can be used whether deleting a single document or multiple documents.

Then, from the client anytime you have multiple documents to delete, always collect them together and make one API call to delete all of them at once.

Internal to the server, how you implement that API depends upon your data store.  If your data store also permits sending multiple documents to delete, then you would likewise call the data store that way.  If it only supports single deletes, then you would just loop and delete each one individually.

Comment: Is there a way to make a service accept BOTH a single docId param OR a list of docIds? Right now from what I've seen it is one or the other and I'd like to avoid having to put single docIds into arrays just to conform with the service's need of supporting multiple ids.

Comment: @Konstantine - sure - it all depends upon how you're sending your parameters to your service. If you were using query parameters, a single delete could look like this: `http;//mydomain.com/api/delete?id=12` and a multiple delete could look like this: `http;//mydomain.com/api/delete?id=12,17,29`

Answer (score 0):

Doing the option `3` would be the most elegant solution for me.

Assuming you send requests like `POST /deleteDocument` where you have `docId` as a  parameter, you could instead pass an array of document ids to remove.

Then in backend you would only have to iterate through the list of ids and perform the deletion. You should be able keep the deletion code relatively intact.

Comment: Wouldn't this solution force the front-end `deleteDoc` action send an `array` of docIds to the server even if it is only one document? I don't really like having to put a single `id` into an array just to comply with the back-end service's need to support multiple ids. This is why option 3 was actually a way to `batch` for example 10 http requests with 10 single docIds that each calls the service by itself. I just don't know if this is possible and how to implement it.